# How to only get data with today's date in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to display only data that has today's date in the created_at timestamp.

But I'm getting all my data instead of only today's data

Here is my code

```
    $now = now();
    $products = Product::selectRaw('status, created_at, date(created_at), hour(created_at), count(*) as total')
                            ->whereRaw('created_at', $now)
                            ->groupByRaw('status, date(created_at), hour(created_at), created_at')
                            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$now = now();
    $products = Product::selectRaw('status, created_at, date(created_at), hour(created_at), count(*) as total')
                            ->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))
                            ->groupByRaw('status, date(created_at), hour(created_at), created_at')
                            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work.

```
 $products = Product::selectRaw('status, created_at, date(created_at), hour(created_at), count(*) as total')
                            ->whereDate('created_at', DB::raw('CURDATE()'))
                            ->groupByRaw('status, date(created_at), hour(created_at), created_at')
                            ->get();
```